# Отписка от событий(слабые события)

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста равносильны ли будут по значению эти 2 события.

Событие 1:
Создаем windows form, подписываемся с помощью делегата на событие о её закрытии:
`form.onClose += incomeCloseEvent;`
после закрытия будет вызвана функция `incomeCloseEvent()`
в которой я обнуляю ссылку:
`form.onClose -= incomeCloseEvent;`

Событие 2:
Создаем windows form, подписываемся с помощью делегата на событие о ее закрытии:
`form.onClose += incomeCloseEvent;`
после закрытия формы в её деструкторе я обнулю ссылку:
`this.onClose = null;`

Comment: По сути да. Равносильно.

Comment: "в её деструкторе" - зачем?

Comment: @Igor чтобы после уничтожения объекта `form` не осталась ссылка на его делегат у подписчика, и не возникло утечки памяти. Как это понимаю я, поправьте если ошибаюсь.

Comment: @K.Oleg, после уничтожения формы, все подписки тоже уничтожаются

Comment: @K.Oleg Метод, используемый в качестве делегата, не знает, что его используют в качестве делегата, и не хранит ссылки на объекты, которые используют его в качестве делегата. Если бы такие ссылки хранились, то деструктор (finalizer?) не вызвался бы.

Comment: @Igor, понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Grundy, а есть речь идет о другом объекте типа `MyType`, при его уничтожении(обнулении ссылки на него) подписки уничтожаются?

Comment: @K.Oleg - если `MyType` - тип объекта, чей метод используется в качестве делегата, то ссылка на него содержится в делегате, и сборщик мусора его не соберет, пока существуют объекты с событиями, использующими эти делегаты.

Comment: @Igor, ясно! спасибо!

Comment: Ну, очевидно, что `= null` убирает все остальные подписки тоже, не только данную.

Comment: 1. Судя по описанию, в вашем примере вообще нет событий. `onClose` -- это обычное поле типа Delegate, которое светится наружу. 2. В C# нет деструкторов, а в финализаторе обнулять ссылки бессмысленно -- если до него добрался GC, это значит, что никаких ссылок, влияющих на жизнь объекта, нет, соответственно обнулять ничего не нужно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, нет никакого смысла отписываться от событий уничтожаемого объекта.

Во-вторых, если под `onClose` вы понимаете [стандартное событие](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed(v=vs.110).aspx) - то присвоить ему null вы не сможете. А заводить свое событие - смысла мало.

В-третьих, начиная с .NET 4.5 появилось новое удобное средство для отслеживания **однократных** событий - задачи (точнее, они появились в 4.0, но удобными стали в 4.5).

Если форма предназначена для однократного показа, то можно сделать примерно так:

```
private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsClosed = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

protected override void OnClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    base.OnClosed(sender, e);
    tcsClosed.SetResult(true);
}

public Task ShowAsync() => ShowAsync(CancellationToken.None);

public async Task ShowAsync(CancellationToken token) {
    if (tcsClosed.Task.IsCompleted) throw new InvalidOperationException("Форма уже была показана");
    using (token.Register(Close, useSynchronizationContext: true)) {
        Show();
        await tcsClosed.Task;
    }
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Теперь в асинхронном методе можно показать форму и дождаться ее закрытия при помощи одного оператора `await form.ShowAsync()`.

Если одну и ту же форму можно показывать несколько раз - надо перенести инициализацию поля tcsClosed в первую строчку метода ShowAsync, заменив условный оператор.

Никаких событий и отписки от них!

---

По теме же вопроса - очевидно, вариант `-= incomeCloseEvent` отписывает один обработчик, а вариант `= null` отписывает все обработчики.

Если гарантируется, что обработчик будет только один - эти два варианта эквивалентны. Но тогда и подписку лучше делать тоже через оператор присваивания: `form.onClose = incomeCloseEvent`, чтобы никому не пришло в голову что обработчиков может быть несколько.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! `onClose` имел ввиду не стандартное событие.